# RxSwift correct way to subscribe to data model property change

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

New to RxSwift here. I have a (MVVM) view model that represents a Newsfeed-like page, what's the correct way to subscribe to change in data model's properties? In the following example, `startUpdate()` constantly updates `post`. The computed properties `messageToDisplay` and `shouldShowHeart` drives some UI event.

```
struct Post {
    var iLiked: Bool
    var likes: Int
    ...
}

class PostViewModel: NSObject {
    private var post: Post

    var messageToDisplay: String {
        if post.iLiked { return ... }
        else { return .... }
    }

    var shouldShowHeart: Bool {
        return iLiked && likes > 10
    }

    func startUpdate() {
        // network request and update post
    }
    ...
}
```

It seems to me in order to make this whole thing reactive, I have to turn each properties of `Post` and all computed properties into `Variable`? It doesn't look quite right to me.

Answer (score 0):

// Class NetworkRequest or any name

```
static func request(endpoint: String, query: [String: Any] = [:]) -> Observable<[String: Any]> {
    do {
        guard let url = URL(string: API)?.appendingPathComponent(endpoint) else {
            throw EOError.invalidURL(endpoint)
        }

        return manager.rx.responseJSON(.get, url)
            .map({ (response, json) -> [String: Any] in
                guard let result = json as? [String: Any] else {
                    throw EOError.invalidJSON(url.absoluteString)
                }
                return result
            })
      } catch {
        return Observable.empty()
      }
}

static var posts: Observable<[Post]> = {
    return NetworkRequest.request(endpoint: postEndpoint)
        .map { data in
            let posts = data["post"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
            return posts
                .flatMap(Post.init)
                .sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
        }
        .shareReplay(1)
}()


class PostViewModel: NSObject {
    let posts = Variable<[Post]>([])
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      posts
       .asObservable()
       .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //self?.tableView?.reloadData() if you want to reload all tableview
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none) // OR if you want to insert one or multiple rows.
            //OR update UI
         }
      })
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)



      posts.asObservable()
     .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { [unowned self] (tableView: UITableView, index: Int, element: Posts) in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell") as! PostCell
//for example you need to update the view model and cell with textfield.. if you want to update the ui with a cell then use cell.button.tap{}. hope it works for you.
        cell.textField.rx.text
            .orEmpty.asObservable()
            .bind(to: self.posts.value[index].name!)
            .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
        return cell
    }

      startDownload()
  }
}

func startDownload {
    posts.value = NetworkRequest.posts
}
```

If you want to change anything then use subscribe, bind, concat .. There are many methods and properties which you can use.

Comment: How does this solve my problem of updating UI when a property of the post changed?

Comment: when posts.value change
      posts
       .asObservable()
       .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in

will call automatically. well it is the main feature of observable or rxswift

Comment: Okay I see, so there is no way for me to just update a single property of `post`, but have to update the whole thing instead?

Comment: please checkout my updated answer. What you have to do is update the array first then use following line no need to reload the whole tableView.

self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

Comment: this is how you find out your indexpath
let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(posts.count - 1), section:0)

Comment: Sorry you probably misunderstood me. I know how to update table view when data changes. I was asking is it possible to just update `iLiked` or `likes` property and drive some UI events, instead of replacing it with a new `post`

Comment: I think you are talking about updating UI or single cell element. For example, you just press a 'Like' button and that button gets highlighted or updates any UI. if Yes, I again updating my answer. Please check.